# Customisation of captions for figures and tables

Tags: captions

I am new to latex and facing difficulties to make customisations.

In my thesis document, requirement of my institution for the captions of the figures and tables is that: Captions should be like "Figure 1.2 xxx" , "Table 2.3 yyy"

However, currently in pdf report of my thesis document Captions are like "FIGURE 1.3: xxx" , "TABLE 2.3: yyy" as below:

[image]

So it would not be all uppercase letter and there should not be ":".

Would you please help me on adjusting the caption options to meet the requirement of my institution?

P.S

Example from my work:

related packages:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{0pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Figure entry in main tex.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{figures/error_photoss.pdf}
    \caption[...]{...}
    \label{fig:some_photo}
\end{figure}
```

Best wishes,

Comment: Please provide us a minimum working example showing the document class (which probably is a template?)  you are using and any related with captions packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please do reveal which document class you employ.

Comment: Hi Miltos, Thanks for your comment. I provided related parts from my tex file.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `Figure` is being written with the `\sc` font, so technically it is not being capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space,labelfont=md}`, this will solve your problem.

Add for tables you can use `\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,labelfont=md}`

Or you can "merge" both an use `\captionsetup{labelsep=space,labelfont=md}`

Link to different `labelsep` [Customizing captions of floating environments∗](https://texdoc.org/serve/caption/0)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false} \setlength{\captionmargin}{0pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup{labelsep=space,labelfont=md}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{figures/error_photoss.pdf} 
\caption[...]{...}
\label{fig:some_photo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use \captionsetup{labelsep=space} Now the caption seems like this "FIGURE 1.2 xxx". It seems to solve omitting ":" Thanks for the tip. However, I am also required to change all uppercase behavior. It should be like "Figure 1.2 xxx".

Comment: @jarvico you can use `labelfont = md`

Comment: perfect, this solved my problem. Thank you so much, really appreciated!

Comment: @jarvico then accept this answer as the solution.